# model selection: trading off fit for other constraints (e.g., interpretability)

Tags: cross-validation, modeling, model-selection, interpretation

I've got some data and my goal is to find a model that fits that data well, but also that is interpretable/intelligible to humans. I've just performed 10 runs of 10-fold cross validation comparing a few different models of this data. Comparing the log-likelihood loss, it's reasonably clear which model performs best. However, as far as I can tell the differences between the models are quite small, and some models are more intelligible than others.

My question is: **are there any good methods or guidelines for deciding when differences in model performance are negligible? Or for choosing among models in ways that trade-off fit for other constraints?** As I said, my concern is the intelligibility of the models, but I could imagine similar considerations being made with respect to performance, memory use, ease of adding features, etc.

So far I've tried to give the performance differences a more interpretable framing by looking at the likelihood ratio of the expected loss. So, where model A's LL is -18.59 and model B's is -18.77, the actual ratio among the likelihoods is ~.84. Which is to say (if I'm doing this right), the data are .84 times as likely under model B as under model A. From there it would be a judgment call, but that strikes me as potentially worth the trade-off I get in intelligibility between the two models.

What do you think of this approach? Are there other (better) approaches I should be using instead?

Comment: Since posting this I've realized that comparing the likelihood ratios of these cross validation results isn't quite right, as the data the likelihoods are computed for aren't identical (due to randomizing cross validation splits).